# Can I replace a directory with a symlink without write permissions in parent?

Tags: permissions, directory, symlink, ln

I would like to replace a directory with a symlink. For the directory itself I have full permissions (`rwx`), but for the parent directory I don't have write permissions (`r-x`).

Is this possible? The man page for `ln` states that `-f` removes existing destination files, which sounds like it would first would delete the directory, then fail to create the symlink, leaving me with nothing.

Comment: You can create first a symlink with a different name, and see if it works.

Comment: It gives me "Permission denied", as expected. I was hoping for an atomic "replacement" command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have write permission in the parent directory, you can't make any changes in the parent directory; this includes deleting the target directory, and creating a symlink.

In any case, `ln` won't overwrite a directory, even with `-f`.